# Showing Data with 2 tables on php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a problem with showing data from 2 tables

```
Table 1 (kegiatan): id_kgt (PK), nama_kgt,ket, tg_mulai, tg_akhir, nm_pengirim, indi01, indi02, indi03, indi04, indi05, indi06, indi07, indi08, indi09, indi010,

Table 2 (pilihan): kdpilih (PK), nmpilih

kdpilih contain number which linked with indi01 to indi010

nmpilih contain plain text, ex: kdpilih: 1 = nmpilih: car
```

I already create the script, but the problem is when someone entry the data less or more than 3 field (indi01, indi02, indi03) from the entry page it will show nothing. Is there any solution to fix this? Is my join tables script wrong? So, i want showing all the data although the data on entry page only 1, 2, 3 or etc.

This is my script, any help wil so helpfull. Thanks

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT a.id_kgt
     , a.nama_kgt
     , a.ket
     , a.tg_mulai
     , a.tg_akhir
     , a.nm_pengirim
     , a.file
     , b.nmpilih AS indi01
     , c.nmpilih AS indi02
     , d.nmpilih as indi03 
  FROM kegiatan a 
  JOIN pilihan b 
    ON b.kdpilih = a.indi01 
  JOIN pilihan c 
    ON c.kdpilih = a.indi02 
  JOIN pilihan d 
    ON d.kdpilih = a.indi03 
 ORDER 
    BY a.id_kgt ASC
 ";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $no = 1;
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
      {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
          echo "<tr>
                  <td>".$data['id_kgt']."</a></td>
                  <td>".$data['nama_kgt']."</a></td>
                  <td>".$data['ket']."</td>
                  <td>".tglindo($data['tg_mulai'])."</td>
                  <td>".tglindo($data['tg_akhir'])."</td>
                  <td>".$data['indi01'].", ".$data['indi02'].", ".$data['indi03']."</td>
                  <td>".$data['nm_pengirim']."</td>
                  <td>
                    <a href='".$data['file']."'>Download</a>   
                    <a href='kegiatan_ubah.php?id_file=$data[id_kgt]'>Ubah</a>   
                    <a href='kegiatan_hapus.php?id_file=$data[id_kgt]'>Hapus</a>
                  </td>
                </tr>";
                $no++;
        }
      }
      else
        {
          echo "No data.";
        }
```

Comment: I can see nothing in the sql that would be affected by user input - ie: there is no where clause - so where / how does this problem manifest itself?

Comment: i don't use where because i want show all the data from that 2 table, but the reality it only showing 3 field from db: indi01, indi02, indi03

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the data on the other tables do not do a join, you may consider left join instead.

Cheers

Comment: when i use left join, it show numbers from kdpilih on pilihan table. could you give me the correct query sir?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
i use this magic:

```
"SELECT a.id_kgt, a.nama_kgt, a.ket, a.tg_mulai, a.tg_akhir, a.nm_pengirim, a.file, 
      b.nmpilih as indi01, c.nmpilih as indi02, d.nmpilih as indi03, e.nmpilih as indi04, f.nmpilih as indi05, 
      g.nmpilih as indi06, h.nmpilih as indi07, i.nmpilih as indi08, j.nmpilih as indi09, k.nmpilih as indi010 
      FROM kegiatan a 
      LEFT JOIN pilihan b ON b.kdpilih = a.indi01 LEFT JOIN pilihan c ON c.kdpilih = a.indi02 
      LEFT JOIN pilihan d ON d.kdpilih = a.indi03 LEFT JOIN pilihan e ON e.kdpilih = a.indi04 
      LEFT JOIN pilihan f ON f.kdpilih = a.indi05 LEFT JOIN pilihan g ON g.kdpilih = a.indi06
      LEFT JOIN pilihan h ON h.kdpilih = a.indi07 LEFT JOIN pilihan i ON i.kdpilih = a.indi08 
      LEFT JOIN pilihan j ON j.kdpilih = a.indi09 LEFT JOIN pilihan k ON k.kdpilih = a.indi010 
      ORDER BY a.id_kgt ASC"
```